# What method to use for storing data for a simple web app project?

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, backend, progressive-web-apps

I am currently learning javascript and I really want to create a web app project.

The purpose of the web app is to offer users mealplan database that they can search based on the single recipes or even ingredients such as (potatoes, hamburger and etc.)

I firstly thought of storing the meal plans as single pdf files, because it would be easier for me to write them, but I also thought of another option that might be better for user experience, which is to make proper app components such as listed items and drop down expanding components.
I am planning to store a significant amount of mealplans therefore I am looking for a relatively easy way to put the data on the app.

Just to let you know that I have zero backend knowledge, so that’s why I am confused which method I should use, that would be future proof.

I would appreciate if you guys point me in the right direction and tell me what to do or learn in order to create this app.

[Web app ui/ux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MAQH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice Designs.

I would highly recommend you to make sure the data is persisted by using a real database for the meals. What ever stack (Node/Express, Python/Flask, PHP/Laravel) you use is not my problem, do what works for you, just have the data persisted.

You already have your UI designed, next up model the data.

Or for now just have a fake data in an object like below to play with:

```
{
    title: "3 meals 1 snack 2300 kcal",
    meals: [
        {
            meal: "meal 1",
            title: "Nandos chicken",
            ingredients: ["asdsad", "sdsds", "asdsadda"],
            instructions: "some instructions here like soo asdsa  asd",
            serving: 2,
            kcal: 452
        }
    ]
    
},
{
    title: "5 meals 1 snack 2300 kcal",
    meals: [
        {
            meal: "meal 1",
            title: "Nandos chicken",
            ingredients: ["asdsad", "sdsds", "asdsadda"],
            instructions: "some instructions here like soo asdsa  asd",
            serving: 2,
            kcal: 452
        }
    ]
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a database, but if the PDF option is compelling for you, I built a site for searching yoga kriyas recently that's similar in function to what you're proposing. There may be an idea or two from it that will help you.

Most of the kriyas were from physical manuals, so I chose searchable PDF as the document format. I put them on AWS S3 and used a lambda function to return a signed URL for the PDF to my web app. That way I could handle larger PDFs and didn't have to expose the entire dataset to the public on S3.

For search, I put the extracted text from the PDFs on Algolia. This architecture eliminated the need for a database. It's also essentially free for me to host since there's no server. I used PDF.js to display the PDFs in a Vue app and Google's Firebase Auth to secure the client.

In my case, I used S3 but there are other cloud storage systems that'll allow you to store large datasets like yours for very little cost.

Here are a few links that might help if you choose this architecture:

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

https://www.algolia.com/

https://vuejs.org/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Answer (score 0):

A backend option seems to suit you. You can use a multitude of languages for your backend, such as Python ([Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)), PHP ([Laravel](https://laravel.com/)), or Node.js ([Express](https://expressjs.com/)). I would suggest using Flask, since it was the easiest for me to start with.

I would suggest using [Corey Schafer's tutorial on Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH) for this. It teaches many important Flask concepts.

Along with that, you can use an SQL database to store your meal plans. Then, you can implement a search feature yourself, or use a tool such as [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) to implement it.